# Using mongoose, can I use a single model to push and update changes on related collections automatically (but not a model instance)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

TL;DR I am trying to create a one to many relationship model, where if I had two collections/tables, I only need to update the second one and the changes would be reflected automatically. Is that possible with MongoDB?

Let's say I have one collection with consistent documents that are almost always going to stay the same, and then I have another collection of documents that need to be updated every 30 seconds fetching data from an API. For example:

**Leagues** (this holds league ids and their name)

```
league_id | league name
-----------------------
1         | Premier League
2         | Bundesliga
3         | Champions League
```

**Fixtures** (this holds data for all the matches that belong to each league)

```
league_id | unix_time | home_team | away_team
---------------------------------------------
1         | 123456789 | Team A    | Team B
2         | 123456789 | Team C    | Team D
1         | 123456789 | Team E    | Team A
```

The easiest thing to do here is to use embedded documents into collection A, but that's not an option for me because I need to expire the fixtures after a given amount of time and you can't expire only nested documents as far as I'm aware.

There is also another challenge which I could best illustrate if I show my schemas.

**leagues.js**

```
const Matches = require('./matches');

const LeaguesSchema = new Schema({
  league_id: { type: Number, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  country: { type: String, required: false },
  fixtures: [
    { type: Number, ref: 'Matches' }
  ]
});

const Leagues = mongoose.model('fixtures', LeaguesSchema);
module.exports = Fixtures;
```

**matches.js**

```
const Matches = require('./matches');

const MatchesSchema = new Schema({
  league_id: { type: Number, ref: Leagues }
  timestamp: Number,
  home_team_name: { type: String, required: true },
  away_team_name: { type: String, required: true },
});

const Matches = mongoose.model('Matches', MatchesSchema);
module.exports = Matches;
```

The end goal here is to be able to use a `Number` which connects table A to table B, and that automatically reflects the queries that the end user makes, say for example a get request for `https://example.com/fixtures?leagues=1,2,3&unix_time_start=123&unix_time_end=456`.

User ask for an array of his/hers favorite leagues which contain games played between unix time A to unix time B time frame.

Now this would have been piece of cake if I had to work with static data for the `fixtures`, but these fixtures contain more info and that info changes by the minute and the document needs to be updated every 30 seconds. There are also other variations like the fixture being deleted so it needs to be removed from the database and whatnot.

In other words, I need to perform complex operations on the **Matches Model**, but from the many tutorials online that I have read so far, they almost always exclusively create **a single instance of the model**, and then just do simple operations with it.

Having related tables add a whole layer of complexity into the mix, so my question is if it is at all possible to do all the CRUD stuff by just using a single Model in one place.

Pseudo-code:

**app.js**

```
const Leagues = require('../schemas/leagues');
const Matches = require('../schemas/matches');

router.post('/something', async (req, res, next) => {
    Matches.insertMany([
        { league_id: 1, unix_time: 123456789, home_team: 'Team A', away_team: 'Team B'},
        { league_id: 2, unix_time: 123456789, home_team: 'Team C', away_team: 'Team D'},
    ])
    // only using the Matches model so far
    // then we use the Leagues model for a query.
    .then(() => {
    Leagues.find({{league_id: { $in: [1,2,3] })
    // use populate() here to add the matches themselves
    .populate('fixtures')
    .then((results) => { console.log(results) })
    })
});
```

---

**UPDATE:** I have figured this out, not sure if that's the *best* way, but it works using virtuals.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals

Relevant part of the code:

```
const LeaguesSchema = new Schema(
  {
    _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, select: false },
    league_id: { type: Number, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    country: { type: String, required: false },
  },
  {
    toObject : { virtuals: true }, toJSON: { virtuals: true }, versionKey: false,
  }
);

LeaguesSchema.virtual('matches', {
  ref: 'Matches',
  localField: 'league_id',
  foreignField: 'league_id',
  justOne: false,
});
```